# Teams Bot: Store Conversation Reference to DB, data limits?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm going to save Conversation Reference to SQL DB.
Conversation Id, Tenant Id, User Id, User Name. (Strings ...)
Could someone tell me about size (length) of the properties above?
Thanks

Comment: You wanna to set the size of each column in a table? If so, try to use Filder to catch some http request when you are using teams client. I used to use Filder to get a conversationId and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly following fields are required for future use from the turnContext -
(PartitionKey, RowKey, TimeStamp, aadid, conversationid, Emailid, Name, ServiceURL, TenandtID, UserUniqueID)
all the fields add up to 1kb of data per row.
Adding this data to db and fetching should not be a costly transaction.

Suggestion: if you are already on azure - rather than adding it to sql, azure table would be good option. It will faster retrieval as well as cost wise more effective.